# Is it safe to only have one stud for each base cabinet in the middle?

Tags: cabinets

I want to install 1 normal base cabinet and 2 pantry cabinets. However the house has studs that are about 24" apart (aside from the leftmost being 22"). I want to make my cabinets all 24" wide.

Is it safe and okay just to attach them to the single stud in the middle?

They will be on a separated toe kick/wood platform. I have been Googling and researching for hours and my head is  worse off and I don't know if it's fools idea or do able and I can't ask my older relatives.

[image: this is the wall, the white lines are the studs, red boxes are the 3 cabinets, the green x's are were i would screw it in]

Comment: Usually for base cabinets on the floor(on legs/supports), screwing into stud/s is optional.  Usually only done if they have any tipping over possibility.

Answer (score 2):

One stud per cabinet should be fine if you attach the cabinets to each other as is typically done. For cabinets with face frames, this attachment is usually achieved by screwing sideways through one face frame into its adjacent face frame(s) (be sure to drill pilot holes with appropriate diameter to avoid splitting hardwood face frames). For frameless cabinets this attachment is usually achieved with sex bolts, e.g. [sex bolts and mating screws](https://www.boltdepot.com/Sex_bolts_and_Mating_screws.aspx):

[image: mating screw]
[image: sex bolt]

Tee nuts and machine screws are much cheaper.

Answer (score 2):

A solid attachment to one stud per base cabinet should be adequate to prevent base cabinets from toppling forward.

If you're concerned about attachment (and this detail is pretty normal for upper cabinets that need full hanging support) provide some blocking between studs at the appropriate height.

I tend to dislike wasted void space, but a board/slat/french cleat across the face of the wall works as well, if you're OK with wasted void space behind the cabinets.

Answer (score 0):

Usually cabinets are shimmed at the floor when needed. Do not expect the floor to be level. If you are building a base which will act as the toe space, be certain it is shimmed level in both directions before setting the cabinets. This will aid in setting them properly a lot. Do screw the sides together, unifying the cabinets together as a whole. 2 screws in each stud will hold the cabinets in place very well.

No need for overkill, the level setting is where all the weight is, not on the wall. In end run cabinets, I place a screw at the bottom so it stays tight to the wall. Unless there is a gap there, where a shim is needed, then screw it.  You may need to shim the top too to keep the cabinet from following a wall that may be out of plumb a bit. When setting cabinets I shim them first and get them to set well together without screws. That will let me see where the shims are needed at the wall. If you have your base level, that will simplify it.